# how to select all elements when some elements are visible and other are not with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium

I have a situation where only 25 emails are visible in frame at a time and rest are hidden. I want to select one email at a time, perform some action and then select next email and hence i wan to perform actions for all emails. When i look for email web element only 25 visible elements are stored in list. I want to discuss that how come i select all email elements at once and store them as list, is it possible. Here is what Im trying

```
  emails = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-time]")
```

This only selects 25 visible emails and hence i can perform action only on 25 visible emails.

```
   for e in emails:
      perform action()
```

Any idea how can i select and u all emails at once in emails list??

Following is the HTML of email div..if needed -

```
<div data- 
convid="AQQkADAwATYwMAItZmQxOC0yZDI2LTAwAi0wMAoAEACWzAD4aUdsTp8hbEQbR2je" 
data-time="2018-05-11T18:02:46+08:00" id="_ariaId_330" aria-selected="false" 
tabindex="-1"><div></div><div autoid="_lvv_d" class="_lvv_H1 _lvv_I1 _lvv_L1 
listItemDefaultBackground" role="option" aria-haspopup="true" aria- 
expanded="false" aria-label="From No-IP.com, Subject May Newsletter + Save 
20%, Received 6:02 PM. " tabindex="0">
```

Comment: Do you need to scroll page down to load more entries?

Comment: Please show the HTML of hidden email, we need a comparison with visible email. The better way is you identify the difference between visible and invisible email on HTML, CSS Style, and figure out how does the page control only 25 items visible( control by CSS Style,  or by next page, or by scroll page down)

Comment: Yes have to scroll down the div to load more emails but problem is that even on scrolling down only 20 emails are visible and above gets hide.